# Find the value of $(x + t)(y + z)$ if $x, y, z, t$ satisfy the following equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

Find the value of $(x + t)(y + z)$ if $x, y, z, t$ satisfy the following equations:

$x+y+2z+3t = 0$

$x+2y+4z+5t = 10$

$3x+2y+z+t = 10$

$5x+4y+2z+t = −10$.

This is fair enough, four equations and four variables, and when I solved this, I got the answer too, but the method is overly lengthy. Is there a short method to do this? using something that I am missing?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try using matrix equations. The question then boils down to finding the inverse of a matrix - there are direct formulas and methods for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no shorter *general* method. A system of equations is a system of equations. There's a shortcut with spotting manipulations that work in this particular case to simplify the problem.

The first and third equations added together give you
$$
   4(x+t) + 3(y+z) = 10.
$$
The second and fourth equations added together give you
$$
   6(x+t) + 6(y+z) = 0.
$$
Now you have a system of two equations in the two "variables" $x+t$ and $y+z$.

Comment: This is really clever.